# How to make a set all lower case in Python 2.7

Tags: python

I have imported a list of the 5000 most common words using csv and I want to make sure they are all lower case. I also need to make it into a set. Is there a special way to do this because it would be way to exhausting to do manually. But should this code work?

```
with open("most_common_words.csv", "rU") as csv_file: # Opens the file in a 'closure' so that when it's finished it's automatically closed"
    most_common = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter = ',', quotechar = '"') # Create a csv reader instance

mcw_set = set(most_common.lower())
```

Thanks!

Comment: `lowers = set(w.lower() for w in most_common)`

Comment: what does the 'w' in w.lower() stand for?

Comment: It's just the index variable in the generator expression, which is like a for loop turned inside out.

Answer (score 5):

This will work:

```
with open("most_common_words.csv", "rU") as csv_file:
    most_common = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter = ',', quotechar = '"')
    mcw_set = set(x[0].lower() for x in most_common)
```

Here is a reference on [generator expressions](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/)

Comment: I tried that and I got this error

    AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'

Comment: The generator should be `x[0].lower()` - csv readers always yield a tuple, even when there's only one string in the line. I'm not sure the `map` implementation can be fixed without defining a helper function, either as a `lambda` or with `def`. Or using `itertools.chain` or something to flatten the virtual sequence of one-element tuples.

Comment: Apologies.  I was thinking of a different system.

Comment: mcw_set = set(x[0].lower() for x in most_common) <<that is what I have right now and it still gave me the same error. I'm not sure if I misunderstood or not

Comment: @user2825385 - That's odd.  Could you give a small sample  of your csv file?

Comment: I really don't see how that could be possible using the code shown - I suspect a typo or accidental reassignment somewhere. BTW, I misspoke - `csv.reader` objects yield lists, not tuples, of strings.

Comment: I apologize, I had a most common word set file and a least common. I forgot to change the least common one. But I came across another error: ValueError: I/O operation on closed file

Comment: Make sure the `set` is constructed inside your `with` block - the whole point of `with` is that it automatically closes the file when you exit the block. And creating the reader doesn't pull any content from the file into memory - that only happens when you iterate over the reader.

Comment: @user2825385 - Happy to have helped!  Please don't put the solution in your question.  Instead, you can accept an answer (click the check next to the answer of your choice) to let people know that this question is answered.

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import imap
from operator import methodcaller

with open("most_common_words.csv", "rU") as csv_file: # Opens the file in a 'closure' so that when it's finished it's automatically closed"
    most_common = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter = ',', quotechar = '"') # Create a csv reader instance

mcw_set = set(imap(methodcaller('lower'), most_common))
```